# Autorun Server Django on Rasberry Pi 4

Tags: python, django, bash, autorun

I have django server, which working corectly when I run rasberry then I open terminal in corrct folder then write :

`source env/bin/activate`
`python manage.py runserver 'my_ip:port`

But I want to do this line automaticly when I turn on Rasberry
So I have solution from youtube which work but not enough.
I have directory /home/pi/.config/autostart
in this directory i have file     'name_file.desktop'

in 'name_file.desktop' :

`[Desktop Entry]`
`Exec = bash /home/pi/Desktop/start.sh`

Also I have file on my desktop    'start.sh'

in 'start.sh' :

`cd /path/to/file`
`source env/bin/activate`
`cd /path/to/file`
`python manage.py runserver 'my_ip:port'`

And that work corectly. I turn on rasberry after about 20 seconds I see  my desktop and I can connect to server Django with wi-fi with my mobile phone. But in this solution I must also connect  monitor to Rasberry. When I have Rasberry without any output devices (like monitor). I only switch on rasberry and wait more time than 20 seconds and then i try and I can not connect to server Django with wi-fi with my mobile phone and I dont know why conecting monitor is nesscecery in this solution.

Has anybody have answer or other solution to autorun server Django when I only turn on raspbeery without output devices ?

Comment: This is because `[Desktop Entry] Exec = bash /home/pi/Desktop/start.sh` depends on Desktop GUI environment. Try to create a service for what you are doing.

Comment: I haved found solution, use crontab --  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVPAHI9on0o

Comment: Using service is more versatile than crontab.